# How to fix 'Pyautogui.mouseUP' and mouseDown issues in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I am currently working on a project where I wanted to automate a GUI using python. I am trying to make some basic mouse movements using pyautogui.

Setup 1 - Here, I am using Windows 7. Commands such as pyautogui.mouseUp, pyautogui.mouseDown are working perfectly fine.

Setup 2 - Here, I am using Windows 10. Commands pyautogui.mouseUp and pyautogui.mouseDown are not working.

Note -

Any suggestions or advises please?

I am using 19 inch desktop monitors in both the cases (both setups). Hence, ruling out resolution issues. '

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the the `pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)` function to move the mouse to a specific point instead of up or down?

Comment: Sure. I will give it a try. Will it also perform similar to mouseUp and mouseDown? I mean, can it be used as an alternative to mouseUp and mouseDown. 2) Is there any issue or blocker w.r.t Windows 10 and any idea why it is not supported pls? Thanks

Comment: @PassionateCoder you must know the coordinates of the location you want to move the mouse to, or you can use the image recognition argument of the function. For the image recognition the argument is a path to the file with the image. I have not tried to use mouseUp() or mouseDown() personally. Every script I wrote I have used pyautogui.moveTo() successfully on windows 10.

Comment: Sure, will give it a try and reply back. Thanks.